# How to center text inside anchor tag

Tags: html, css

I want my anchor tag look like a button, and created this style [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3SE8L/)

```
.details-button {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 0, #FAB149 2%, #F89406 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 1px solid #FAB149;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #999999;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #999999;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #999999;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    -ms-text-shadow: 0 -1px #099FDF;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px #099FDF;
    margin: 4px;
    height: 28px;
    width: 85px;
    vertical-align: central;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: menu;
    display: inline-block;
    /*padding: 6px 0 5px 18px;*/
}
```

It looks as I want, but how to center text horizontally and vertically inside anchor tag?

Comment: Vertical centering can be done using line-height. And horizontaly using text-align.

Comment: Just FYI: "align-items" isn't a real thing yet for most web browsers. Additionally, it only applies to containers with display: flex or display: inline-flex, and then only to block elements inside said containers, not text itself.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Add

```
text-align: center;
line-height: 28px;
```

working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3SE8L/2/

Comment: Looks good, can I ask what is line-height and where did you take the number 28? :)

Comment: It sets how high simple line of text should be. And I set it to 28, because that's the value you set as element `height`. It makes your line fill entire space and automatically makes the content centered vertically.

Comment: @ArsenMkrt line-height is the height of each line of text in an element, including leading above and below the line. For a single line of text, if you set this to your container height it will center the text.

Comment: ahh, ok, but however it looks magic for me, that we set line-weight equal to button height and text arrange to center, line height is the height between two lines in the text, isn't it?

Comment: Thank you, the "line-height" property did the trick for me.

Answer (score 13):

`line-height` and `padding` work if the height of the element is hard-coded, but I like to use

```
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

to keep text centered in a tags where the height may change.

Comment: What you're doing here is centering the anchor tag, not centering the text in the anchor tag.

Comment: @Jamie Marshall Actually it centers the text in the anchor tag if you add that code to your anchor tag (and not its container).

Answer (score 4):

To align your text in the center horizontally and in the middle vertically, try this:

CSS: **[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/3SE8L/3/)**

```
.details-button{
  //your existing styles
  //height: 28px; <-- remove this entry

  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
 }
```

Comment: padding made button bigger

Comment: @ArsenMkrt, maybe but you can edit the padding to what you want 2px 3px etc, or use EMs like '.75em' etc. Right?

Comment: well, yes, but however I want my button to have 28px height... or need to remove height and control height by padding... thanks however for another way how to do this

Answer (score 3):

First, remove this style declaration; it is invalid markup:

```
vertical-align: central;
```

Next, add this to center your text horizontally:

```
text-align: center;
```

Finally, make your height auto and instead of a line-height declaration, set the padding to taste:

```
height:auto;
padding:3px 0;
```

That should do it! Be sure to remove the invalid declaration as it can cause your CSS to break in some browsers.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
{
   display: grid;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply `text-align: center;` in your existing class.

Comment: nice, but it set only horizontally

Comment: Ah, I missed the "and vertically" in your question. That is much trickier to do automatically.

Answer (score -1):

So simple, just add

```
text-align: center;
```

to your targeted class.

Comment: "but how to center text horizontally and vertically inside anchor tag?" your answer is only horizontally.

Comment: margin-top:auto; & margin-bottom: auto;